# Im trying to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY DESC with OUTER APPLY (2 tables), cannot get DESC order

Tags: sql, outer-apply

I am using the following query and i manage to get results ordered by **Id** ASC (from Table2), however I want to get the result ordered by **Id** (table2) DESC.

Table 1:

| ID | CustomerNumber | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1023 | 000001 | Name1 | Surname1 |
| 1024 | 000002 | Name2 | Surname2 |

Table 2:

| Id | CustomerNumber | InvoiceNr | InvoiceMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14435 | 001394 | 98412018 | 9-2018 |
| 14436 | 002061 | 98422018 | 9-2018 |

```
SELECT c.ID, c.CustomerNumber, c.Name, c.Surname, c.Area, c.City, c.Address, c.PhoneNumber, c.CustomerTypeID, c.Enabled, c.DateCreated, p.Id, p.Debit, p.Credit
                FROM TblCustomer c OUTER APPLY
                     (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 p.*
                      FROM TblPayments p
                      WHERE c.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
                     )p WHERE c.ID =  1023
```

[image: the results in SQL]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: You've already been asked for sample data (not [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data) over 8 hours ago. If you post a question you [really should revisit every so often](https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive) to see if someone has commented and asked for clarification

Comment: I see no ORDER BY at all.

Comment: I edit my question and provided samples @D-Shih
Stu, you are right, however, for now I am situated in some African country which is a bit different from a normal world.

Answer (score 1):

The following query solved my problem:

```sql
SELECT c.ID as pid, c.CustomerNumber, c.Name, c.Surname, c.Area, c.City, c.Address, c.PhoneNumber, c.CustomerTypeID, c.Enabled, c.DateCreated, p.Id, p.Debit, p.Credit
                FROM TblCustomer c OUTER APPLY
                     (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 p.*
                      FROM TblPayments p
                      WHERE c.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
                      ORDER BY p.id DESC 
                     ) p WHERE c.ID = 1023
```

I hadn't included the following line to the query:

```sql
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```